# ios loop through JSON?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am receiving a `JSON array` from my server that has the following format:

```
{ messageArray: 
   [ { msgFrom: 'V351315826',
       msgDate: Tue Oct 29 2013 04:00:35 GMT+0000 (UTC),
       msgBody: 'Hi?',
       channelID: 'V351315826' },
     { msgFrom: 'V351315826',
       msgDate: Tue Oct 29 2013 04:00:38 GMT+0000 (UTC),
       msgBody: 'Hello!',
       channelID: 'V351315826' } ] }
```

How can i loop through it?

What is got so far is:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [(NSString *) message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];
NSArray *messageArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"messageArray"];

// Parse and loop through the JSON
for (NSDictionary * dataDict in messageArray) {
    NSString * messageID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * msgFrom = [dataDict objectForKey:@"msgFrom"];
    NSString * msgTime = [dataDict objectForKey:@"msgDate"];

    NSLog(@"FROM ---> %@", dataDict);

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to loop through each msgFrom, msgDate, channelID from within the messageArray

Comment: Is there a problem? The code you have looks like a good start.

Comment: I cant get it to print anything not sure why :/

Comment: Well, you're not printing anything in your code.

Comment: Updated the question code :)

Comment: Did you initialize `deserializedData`?

Comment: deserializedData is the `JSON array` within a `NSString`

Comment: Show the declaration and initialization, don't make us keep guessing how you have things set up. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a method that takes an error pointer, it's a good practice to set your `NSError` to `nil` in non-ARC code (redundant in ARC) and check the return value for `nil` and examine the returned `NSError`:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary *JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [(NSString *) message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];

if (!JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else
{
    NSArray *messageArray = [JSON objectForKey:@"messageArray"];

    // Parse and loop through the JSON
    for (NSDictionary * dataDict in messageArray) {
        NSString * messageID = [dataDict objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * msgFrom = [dataDict objectForKey:@"msgFrom"];
        NSString * msgTime = [dataDict objectForKey:@"msgDate"];

        NSLog(@"FROM ---> %@", dataDict);
    }
}
```

Running this with the supplied JSON prints this to the console:

```
2013-10-28 22:28:20.552 SO question[12141:907] The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)
```

It seems that `NSJSONSerialization` is having a hard time parsing this. I'm not too familiar with JSON myself. Let's see what happens when we run the JSON through a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com) (Paste the JSON into http://jsonlint.com one of many validators on the web). Doing so gives several syntax errors. Seems that keys must be in double quotes and strings must be in double quotes as well. I'll assume all the values in the two dictionaries are strings. After cleaning up the syntax, the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "messageArray": [
        {
            "msgFrom": "V351315826",
            "msgDate": "TueOct29201304: 00: 35GMT+0000(UTC)",
            "msgBody": "Hi?",
            "channelID": "V351315826"
        },
        {
            "msgFrom": "V351315826",
            "msgDate": "TueOct29201304: 00: 38GMT+0000(UTC)",
            "msgBody": "Hello!",
            "channelID": "V351315826"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which prints out the following when I run it through your code:

```
2013-10-28 22:36:02.018 SO question[12188:907] FROM ---> {
    channelID = V351315826;
    msgBody = "Hi?";
    msgDate = "TueOct29201304: 00: 35GMT+0000(UTC)";
    msgFrom = V351315826;
}
2013-10-28 22:36:02.018 SO question[12188:907] FROM ---> {
    channelID = V351315826;
    msgBody = "Hello!";
    msgDate = "TueOct29201304: 00: 38GMT+0000(UTC)";
    msgFrom = V351315826;
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Good job on checking `JSON` instead of `error`. You don't actually need to initialize `err`, though it's not a bad habit, to get into. If `JSON` is `nil`, it is guaranteed to be properly initialized; if not, it's not guaranteed to still be `nil` or even valid.

Comment: I was thinking that OjbC local variables, unlike ivars in the language, held junk values unless explicitly initialized and the paranoid programmer in me preferred to go defensive. But, it does seem to be created with `nil` anyways.

Comment: No, they do hold junk if you don't initialize them (that's why I said not a bad habit), but even if you do initialize it they're not guaranteed to still be valid after the call if the call succeeds.

Comment: @Kevin With ARC they will be set to `nil` implicitly (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) but still, as you both say, not a bad habit!

Comment: Hmmm. That's interesting.